# Custom Promotion for Selected Products When Using Specific Shipping Method

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm a trying to create a module in Magento that will allow the admin to select products and categories that are eligible for a discount on shipping when using a specific shipping method.

I began by making a custom section in System->Config and adding an enable/disable option using the system.xml file for each product individually. When the rate for the shipping method is calculated, I would scan the items in the cart and if one was enabled in the admin, the discount would be applied.

My problem is that this method is only really feasible for stores with a small amount of products. I suspect that there is a better way to solve this problem within Magento, but I have not had much luck finding any information on the topic so far. Is there a better way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create an attribute **'eligible_for_discount'** with options **Yes/No**

2) Create a CSV file having **product_id** and assign attribute **'eligible_for_discount'** with values **'Yes/No' (i.e. 1 or 0)** to whichever products you want to have discount applied.

3) Import the CSV file from Magento Admin.

4) On the cart page you can check if the product contains the attribute value for 'eligible_for_discount' and if **Yes**, then apply discount.

Comment: Thanks Vikram, that is essentially how I ended up solving the problem. I'll post another answer later today going into a little more detail.

Comment: I ll be waiting here to see your updated and precise answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While the other answer was great as a guide, there were a couple of things that gave me some trouble that I want to try and clarify. I decided to create a product attribute using an install script. I placed the following code in my mysql4-install-0.1.0.php file:

```
$entity = $this->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product');

$this->addAttribute($entity, 'reduced_shipping', array(
    'type'      => 'varchar',
    'input'     => 'boolean',
    'label'     => 'Product Qualified For Free Shipping',
    'visible'   => true,
    'default'   => '0',
    'required'  => true,
    'used_in_forms' => array(
        'adminhtml_checkout',
        'adminhtml_customer',
        'admin_html_customer_address',
        'checkout_register',
        'customer_account_create',
        'customer_account_edit',
        'customer_address_edit',
        'customer_register_address',
    )
));
```

While boolean is a valid form of *input* when creating attributes, it looks like it cannot be used to store the attribute *type*. This can be solved by using varchar instead. After the setup script has been run, the admin can go to Catalog->Manage Products, where they can select Yes or No for the Free Shipping attribute on each item.

Finally, I used the following in the collectRates() method of the Carrier that I created to cycle through the items in the customer's cart and see if the admin has selected them for free shipping.

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$itemList = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();

foreach($itemList as $item)
{
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
    if($product->getReducedShipping() == 1)
    {
         //update the price of shipping here
    } 
}
```

I've skimmed over a couple things to keep this answer from getting too long, so let me know if there is any part that I can clarify.